# Getting started with Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios4

I have recently got a Mac and I have downloaded Xcode 4.2 from the store. I am trying to get to grips with iPhone development but I am having real troubles. All the tutorials I seem to find online, when they create a project, they had a resources folder, and inside that there is xib file which allows them to use an interface builder.

This does not appear on 4.2, so makes it kinda hard to follow majority of tutorials have the resources folder. How do I get this back? Or how do I access this file on 4.2?

Also, I could someone explain to me where the objects list is? I started following this tutorial

http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/

as it seemed to be using Xcode 4.2, but when I get down to the storyboard section, it says

"Of course, we really want another tab on there so we can see the switching between the two – so lets drag in another Navigation Controller from the Utilities (objects) list and plonk it down somewhere. "

Except I cannot find this objects list? How do I open this objects list? What am I missing?

Sorry if these questions seem very basic, I am new to both Macs and iPhones. Android development seems a HELL of a lot easier from what I can see so far.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Also would be grateful if anyone could point in direction of any good up to date tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a post on http://www.armandvanderwalt.co.za it will give you a nice understanding of how most stuff fits together, I don't use Interface Builder at all since it only makes the app bigger. Have a look at my blog post, still need to do styling, and add more posts but it is a nice beginner guide.

Most posts you are finding still use XCode 3 that's why you can't find certain things.

Also have a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com

What they are referring to as the object list, in XCode 4 it is found in the bottom right corner of Interface Builder. In XCode 4 Interface Builder is part of XCode and no longer an external application. Therefore when ever you open a XIB file Interface Builder also automatically opens

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tutorial link. I must say it takes a lot of getting used to moving from Android to iPhone development. Quick question, you said you don't use Interface Builder? Is it not easier to drag and drop objects and edit the functionality from the code?

Comment: It may be easier when you start out with it, just to get a hang of it, but XIB files makes the app size larger than it really needs to be, also you have more fine grained control when you just do everything in code. I love iOS dev, I do both and will always prefer iOS dev over Android.